# cannot show json data in line highchart

Tags: json, highcharts, dashboard

I'm new in working with highchart. i have string that is in json format and i created it with newtonsoft. the format of this **string** is like below:

```
[{"Name":"Month","Data":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]},{"Name":"Erlang","Data":[50,72,106,129,144,176,136,148,216,194,96,54]}]
```

I want to import it to a highchart in javascript. The java script code is :

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Erlang',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Amount'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.Name + '</b><br/>' +
                        this.x + ': ' + this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: []
            }

            $.getJSON("../../api/Chart/GetLineJson", function (json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['Data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
```

But it does not work. between the controler url *(api/Chart/GetLineJson)* works well.
I cannot find where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `Name` and `Data` keys in your json response to be lowercase.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Month",
        "data": ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Erlang",
        "data":[50,72,106,129,144,176,136,148,216,194,96,54]
    }
]
```

Working [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/tecaqolucu/edit?js,output) example

Comment: I changed it to lowercase, but it does not work again. when i hard code the data in js, like your sample it works but when i import the data from controller(../../api/Chart/GetLineJson) it does not work. i'm sure that the format of json file is correct, but the result of GetLineJson is a string. is there any problem for this type?

Comment: Run the [console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui) and observe what kind of errors do you have

Comment: I solved it by using  var jsondata= JSON.parse(json) in getJSON :) many thanks for your help.